# Page position on a ViewPager when change from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a problem when I change from portrait to landscape orientation when programing a gallery. The page position in the method `PageAdapter.instantiateItem(View container, int position)` turns 0 when change the screen orientation. I want to store the current page position to keep in this page when the orientation changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the currently displayed page in your saved instance state. For how to save state, please read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState).

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the current item
    savedInstanceState.putInt("current_item", pager.getCurrentItem());

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

After an orientation change, that state can be [restored](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState) and used to set your pagers position.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentItem = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_item");
    }
}
```

Call `pager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentItem);` e.g. in your `onStart()` or `onResume()` method.

For how to get and set the currently selected item read the `ViewPager` documentation:

[getCurrentItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem())

[setCurrentItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int))